# How can I identify users of my API when they call it in JS?

Tags: javascript, api

I've built an API that people are meant to use in javascript (client-side, not Node.js). The problem is I need to know who is using my API. If I have people include an API key in their ajax calls to my API, anybody could see their API key and use it.

How do I identify users of my API if they are calling it from their JS?

```
$.ajax(function(){
  url: "http://usefulapi.com/get-things?api_key=123412341234134", // Anybody can see my API key.
  data: { some_data }
});
```

Comment: 1) Use public and private key encryption. 2) Assign keys to domains only, so that a key is only valid when the request comes from a specific domain.

Comment: What language is the API written in? PHP?

Comment: Node in this case, but I think it's relevant to a rails API I need to work on as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, we use a combination of public and private key encryption for API access. The private key is known only to the API, and you can create a hash based on both the public and private key, and check they match on the server-side.

Next, it's a good idea to limit the keys to a specific domain. In PHP you could easily use the `$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']` super-global to check where the request came from. The following pseudo-code should give you some pointers:

```
$domain = basename($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);    
$apiKey = $_REQUEST['api_key'];
// Now, get the private key for this domain
// Check the private and public keys match
// The request is either allowed or denied.
```

As you'll see, it's worth adding an authentication table to your database, and storing the domain, public key and private keys inside, so you can authenticate the request.